# Adjusting percentages in decomposition tree in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, tree, decomposition

I was wondering if it's possible in Power BI to construct a decomposition tree in which the percentages assigned to each node are the contribution of that node to its parent node, rather than its contribution to the overall total. I've given a picture to show what I mean (it represents a budget allocated to some departments and sub-departments). I would like to obtain the bottom tree from the top tree. Thanks! [image]

Comment: Have you tried using the [Decomposition Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-decomposition-tree) visual in Power BI?

Comment: @SamNseir Yes, but I can't figure out how to change the settings on the tree to give me the weights that I want. The decomposition tree automatically computes the weight of a node to be the sum of the weights of its "child" nodes. I need something a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Bars > Options `Scale to` = `Parent node`.

[image]

**Update**
If you are wanting to display the percentages, then you will need to create a measure similar to this:

```
Tree% = 
  SWITCH(TRUE(),
    ISINSCOPE(Tree[L3]), DIVIDE([TreeSum], CALCULATE([TreeSum], ALLSELECTED(Tree[L3])) ),
    ISINSCOPE(Tree[L2]), DIVIDE([TreeSum], CALCULATE([TreeSum], ALLSELECTED(Tree[L2])) ),
    ISINSCOPE(Tree[L1]), DIVIDE([TreeSum], CALCULATE([TreeSum], ALLSELECTED(Tree[L1])) ),
    1
  )
```

Ensure the `SWITCH` statement starts with the lowest level of the tree.
`[TreeSum]` is a measure of `SUM('yourTable'[relavant value])`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @SamNseir. I followed your suggestion and the lengths of the bars are proportional to the nodes' contributions to their parent nodes. However, the percentages that appear below each bar still give the nodes' contributions to the grand total, even if you do select "Scale to Parent node". Is there any way to change these percentages so that they're also scaled to the parent node?

Comment: Updated answer above with a measure that you will need to use to display the percentages of a node.